# Trouble Using JavaScript to Insert HTML Img Tag

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I'm using the following code:

```
var oDiv = document.createElement ("DIV");
oDiv.innerHTML='<img src="{{ url_for(\'static\', filename=\'images/bubble4.png\') }}">'
```

to try and insert an image from my javascript file into my html file. As you can see, I'm using flask. The innerHtml seems to be working because the broken image links do appear.
I think the problem is coming from all of the different double and single quotes in flask's url_for syntax, but I can't figure out how to properly escape them. If I manually add the img tag to my HTML, the image shows up just fine.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I can avoid the problem by not using the Jinja templating and just putting in the relative url, but I'd like to be able to use Jinja.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `{{ ... }}` template tag does not have to worry about quoting in JavaScript, as it'll be replaced by the URL before it is ever interpreted as JavaScript.

In other words, there is no need to escape those quotes:

```
oDiv.innerHTML = '<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/bubble4.png') }}">';
```

However, if you are placing this in a JavaScript file located in your `static/` folder, then it'll never execute the Jinja2 code; that only applies to dynamic templates, not static assets.

Make sure you put this in a template; you can have your main macro add this URL as a `data-` attribute to your HTML body, for example:

```
<body data-bubble-img="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/bubble4.png') }}">
```

then have you javascript load that:

```
var bubble_img = $('body').data('bubble-img');
oDiv.innerHTML = '<img src="' + bubble_img + '">';
```

Comment: That makes sense, I think, but when I stop escaping the quotes and use the code as you suggest, the broken imgs disappear.

Comment: Then look at what the exact output is that the server produced. Use the browser 'view source' option (Chrome: View -> Developer -> View Source) and see exactly what was generated.

Comment: Ok I think we're getting close the URL source on the broken image is: %7B%7B%20url_for('static',%20filename='images/bubble4.png')%20%7D%7D Whereas the url on the image that I manually added is much nicer looking: /static/images/bubble4.png So it seems like something in the formatting is still off.

Comment: That means that your Jinja2 code *was not executed at all*; that is the `{{ .. }}` url-escaped.

Comment: Are you certain that your file is not a static file?

Comment: Wait, which file? My HTML is in a templates folder and everything else is in a static folder.

Comment: Yes, and this line is located where exactly?

Comment: It's located in the javascript file, which is a static file? Which I'm guessing is going to be a problem?

Comment: Yes, because static files are not processed as Jinja templates.

Comment: Ahhh... I see. I guess I'll have to think about restructuring a bit then. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

The jinja part is executed on the server, the result is sent to the client, which will then execute (or not...) the javascript code. IOW the jinja part doesn't need any escaping (but you need to make sure the *resulting code* is properly quoted / escaped).

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'need to make sure the resulting code is escaped'? (Because I get the feeling I'm not doing that...)